# Association entity is valid in LINQPad but null at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, associations, linqpad

Let's assume I have some car related entities. A `Vehicle` class and a `VehicleType` class.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set}
    public int VehicleTypeId {get; set;}
    public virtual VehicleType VehicleType {get; set;}
}

public class VehicleType
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string VehicleTypeName {get; set}
    public ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Price> Prices {get; set;}
}

public class Price
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Price {get; set;}
    public int VehicleTypeId {get; set;}
    public virtual VehicleType VehicleType {get; set;}
}
```

The `VehicleType` table serves as a relationship table to both the Vehicle table and the Price table. I am trying to use LINQ to get at the `Price` for a given `Vehicle` based upon it's `VehicleType`...

```
var myVehicle = dbContext.Vehicles.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == 1234);
var myVehiclePrice = myVehicle.VehicleType.Prices.Select(p => p.Price);
```

Now when using LINQPad this query works well when I use my database as the source. I get back the Price as expected. However, when using this inside Visual Studio an exception is thrown on ..

```
var myVehiclePrice = myVehicle.VehicleType.Prices.Select(p => p.Price);
```

The exception is that `VehicleType` is null. I know there is data there, I am just not sure why `VehicleType` is showing as `null`.

And yes I am using the same connection string in my `web.config` and LINQPad.

EDIT: I should note that when using LINQPad I was using C# Expressions rather than C# Statements.

**Solution**: I was able to get it working. In the end, in order to get the prices, I had to include BOTH the `VehicleType` and `Price` entities in the Include statement.

```
var myVehcilePrice = myVehicle.Include("VehicleType.Prices").Single(v => v.Id == 1234).VehicleType.Prices
```

Note that you want to include the association name in the Include statement. Thanks to TheGeekYouNeed for the help on Include.

Comment: Sounds like your Entity Framework model is wrong. Are you using the same dll for your 'typed data context' in LinqPad as you are using with Visual Studio. Also check the value for myVehicle.VehicleTypeId with both projects.

Comment: I think part of my problem is my connection was using the database connection string and therefore defaulting to LINQ to SQL. I changed the LINQPad connection to use the dll of my data assembly. `VehicleType` is now populated but now the Price collection is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myVehicle = dbContext.Vehicles.Where(v => v.Id == 1234).Include("VehicleType").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What does the Include do? Is it acting as a type of `JOIN`?

Comment: It includes the data for all corresponding child entities from your query of type VehicleType

Comment: I am not seeing the `Include` in intellisense? Is that expected?

Comment: I edited my answer - had the include in the wrong order.  And placed your conditions in a Where clause.

Comment: I tried this in LINQPad and it worked yet I am unsure how to get just the prices to list? The prices are nested inside the VehicleType.